How to set width/height of widgets within a Paned Window widget in Tkinter after initialization?
I'm trying to create a save/restore functionality in my Tkinter GUI, but I'm having trouble restoring the width/height of Widgets within a Paned Window. I've tried .place() and .config, but the resizable window around each of the widgets disappears and I can no longer resize each widget.
Example code:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
pw = PanedWindow(root)

text1 = Text(pw)
pw.add(text1)

text2 = Text(pw)
pw.add(text2)

entry1 = Entry(pw)
pw.add(entry1)


EDIT: No longer using TTK
EDIT2: No longer using Tkinter. Switched to PyQt5 and everything just works.

Have you tried using the .paneconfig method on the PanedWindow (docs)?

There is no code on save/restore functionality.  Also your example code does not call any layout function on pw so the paned window is hidden.  It is better to provide a [mre] and elaborate more on your issue.

@TheLizzard I've tried to do that, but it doesn't seem to modify the child widgets height/width.

Just use PyQt5. Don't bother with Tkinter (Or worse, the TTK library).

I'm not sure PaneWindows make sense singularly.  You might need a minimum of 2, paired.  Also, some bogus content helps for the widgets to have something to grasp to.
Here is my gadget.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
pw = PanedWindow(root)
pw.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
text1 = Text(pw)
text1.insert(INSERT, "text1 .....")
pw.add(text1)

pw2 = PanedWindow(pw, orient=VERTICAL)
pw.add(pw2)
text2 = Text(pw)
text2.insert(INSERT, "text2 .....")
pw2.add(text2)


entry1 = Entry(pw)
pw.add(entry1)


Entry1 is in error as it's parented to the first pane.  All 3 windows should be parented by a 4th window.

Right now, one of your PanedWindows only contains text2 and no other widgets. You probably wanted to write pw2.add(entry1) instead of pw.add(entry1)

Note that OP used only one instance of ttk.PanedWindow to hold the two Text widgets and one ttk.Entry widget.  It is not necessary to use second instance of ttk.PanedWindow.

Panedwindows are designed to have multiple child windows. There’s no need to use two panedwindows.

You can save the position of sashes with pw.sashpos(i). Something like this:
def save():
    sash_pos = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            sash_pos.append(pw.sashpos(i))
            i += 1
        except TclError:
            break

    with open("sash_pos.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(sash_pos, f)

    root.destroy()

And then load them with pw.sashpos(i, pos) like this:
def load():
    try:
        with open("sash_pos.json", "r") as f:
            sash_pos = json.load(f)
        print(sash_pos)
        for i, pos in enumerate(sash_pos):
            pw.sashpos(i, pos)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

Just make sure window is fully loaded before calling the load function. something like pw.after(100, load) worked for me.
